# Django Syntax Error when trying to syncdb

Tags: django

I am doing a tutorial from HackedExistence and am getting the following error when trying to syncdb:

```
class Beer(models.Model):
    ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am running Django on a virtualenv

Code is as follows:

```
BEER_CHOICES = (
    ('D', 'Domestic'),
    ('I', 'Import'),

class Beer(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.Slugfield(unique=True)
    brewery = models.foreignKey('Brewery')
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=1, choice=BEER_CHOICES)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Brewery(models.Model):

    name    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug    = models.Slugfield(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 4):

[Choices should be defined in a list or tuple of two-tuples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices).
You've forgotten the end-bracket of your tuple.

```
BEER_CHOICES = ( 
    ('D', 'Domestic'), 
    ('I', 'Import'),
) # <- missing end-bracket
```